# How translate this curl to download csv from kibana to python-requests?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl, kibana

Hello I am trying to translate this curl to python requests

```
curl -u user:password -X POST -H "kbn-xsrf: reporting" --insecure https://elk.cloud.dive.tech:5601/api/reporting/generate/csv_searchsource\?jobParams\=......
```

to

```
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'passwrod'
HOST = 'https://url'
API_PATH = """...."""
PORT = 5601

headers = {"kbn-xsrf": "reporting"}

requests.post(f'{HOST}:{PORT}{API_PATH}', headers=headers, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASSWORD)).content
```

But when execute this with python I get the following error:

> b'{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"[request query]:
> types that failed validation:\n- [request query.0.jobParams\\]:
> definition for this key is missing\n- [request query.1]: expected
> value to equal [null]"}'

Any idea about how can I do this query in python?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing the URL manually to ensure it's not something simple like the string not being formatted correctly? like with a missing ":" or "/" somewhere?

Comment: I copied several times, I encode into b64 and decode too.

Comment: What data are you giving the URL? it looks like jobParams is getting URL GET parameters rather than POST fields, so perhaps server side it accepts both. have you tried using requests.get() with a dictionary of your parameters, such as, requests.get(url, params = {'arg1': 12345, 'arg2': 'banana'}, headers = headers, verify = False, auth = (user, password)). Requests renders these into the URL like any other GET request, can you try that and see what it says?